# Scons setup.py script failing - doesn't like __revision__ line

Tags: scons

I downloaded Scons 2.5.1 to Ubuntu Linux 14.04 (Python 2.7.6). The files were extracted into directory scons-2.5.1. Running

```
sudo ./setup.py install
```

as instructed by the README.txt file, gives an error:

```
: File name too long
./setup.py: 35: ./setup.py: __revision__: not found
```

line 35 in setup.py is:

```
__revision__ = "src/setup.py rel_2.5.1:3735:9dc6cee5c168 2016/11/03 14:02:02 bdbaddog"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking at the script and noticed it has no #!/usr/bin/python line. Re-reading the README.txt I see that I misread it. You need to explicitly invoke Python to run the script:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```